# helm getting subchart service names

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

Whats the best way to get the helm subchart service names to reference into my ingress controller that will sit in the parent chart

```
values.yaml
---
ingress:
  paths:
    - serviceName: app-1
      path: /app-1/*
      port: 8080
    - serviceName: app-2
      path: /app-2/*
      port: 8080


ingress.yaml 
---
{{- range .Values.ingress.paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            backend:
              {{- $subchart := .serviceName -}}
              serviceName: {{- include "$subchart.fullname" .}}
              servicePort: {{ .port }}
        {{- end }}
```

template: no template "$subchart.fullname" associated with template "gotpl"

Answer (score 9):

helm 3.7 version has solved the problem
https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/9957.
You can use like this

```
{{ template "bar.fullname" .Subcharts.bar }}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about hardcoded subchart name scoped by release ?

`{{ .Release.Name }}-<subchart_name>`

Comment: It would fail when the name length is over X. Because most charts get the name from a template function which truncates the assembled name.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the best way to reference a service name is to override the template that they are using. There are some caveats to doing this however.

1. The subchart and your chart will have different contexts so they will most likely render the template differently
2. There are some things that are only available to the subchart

Most charts have a template similar to the one below in their _helpers.tpl file.

```
{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
If release name contains chart name it will be used as a full name.
*/}}
{{- define "newchart.fullname" -}} 
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride }}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride }}
{{- if contains $name .Release.Name }}
{{- .Release.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

The subchart has different `.Values` to your chart. We will fix this when we render this template by creating a context that is similar to the subcharts context.

Instead of calling it with the `.` context we create a new context by replacing the `.Values` with the subcharts `.Values`.

```
{{ template "newchart.fullname" (set (deepCopy .) "Values" .Values.newchart }}
```

We use deepCopy so that we don't actually change the `.` context but rather create a new one to use.

The subchart has access to its own `.Chart` values that we can't replicate. In this case we will have to hardcode the value of `.Chart.Name` to the template. In this we can just replace it with the chart name `newchart`.

Once we have done this both `nameOverride` and `fullnameOverride` on the subchart will work without you having to manually change anything in your template files.

Answer (score 1):

If the subchart uses the `fullname` function from `_helpers.tpl` (provided by helm by default for new charts) you can use this (replace `postgresql` with the name of the subchart):

```
{{- $fullName := include "postgresql.fullname" (mustMerge (dict "Chart" (dict "Name" "postgresql") "Values" .Values.postgresql) (deepCopy .)) -}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the sub-chart definition!

As an example, `elasticsearch` chart, see here https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/templates/service.yaml, is defining 2 services.

Both services name can be declared as value `clusterName`.